# Proving that uncountable sets are of the same cardinality

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

In this week's discrete mathematics' class, we received the following 2 exercise subsections:

1. prove that the sets: $[a,b],(a,b)$ have similar cardinalities.
2. prove that the sets: $(a,b),(0,1)$ have similar cardinalities.
3. if we know that $A=\{x\in \mathbb N,2|x\},B=\{x\in \mathbb N, 3|x\},$ prove that $C=A\cup B$ has the same cardinality.

I'm lost, especially with the 2 first questions. In the third one, I have succeded in proving that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality, but can't seem to find a bijective function from $A$ to $C$.

Comment: In the first one, you can start by showing that $[a,b] = (a,b)\cup \{a\}\cup \{b\}$.

Comment: There's no such thing as "similar cardinalities". Cardinalities of two sets are either the same or different.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about your problems?

Comment: @ClementYung I guess it means equal cardinalities.

Comment: Currently, $C$ has a cardinality of $1$. You probably didn't mean to add the parentheses { }.

Comment: Fixed, and indeed I meant equal cardinalities.

Comment: There are probably several other duplicates as well. Please search before posting your questions, and please keep them focused.